# Triggering Jenkins builds remotely with post-commit hook on Windows

Tags: svn, batch-file, jenkins, post-commit-hook

I'm setting up my Subversion post-commit hook to trigger a Jenkins build remotely when a commit is made.

First I changed `post-commit.tmpl` to `post-commit.bat` and then:

I tried this first:

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
C:/wget_for_win/wget http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/my_project/build
```

Then I committed some code, and it worked as expected.
But this will only build one project, but I want it more flexible so I changed `post-commit.bat` to the one I found on the [Jenkins Subversion Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin):

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET UUID=`svnlook uuid %REPOS%`
C:/wget_for_win/wget \
 --header="Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
 --post-data="svnlook changed --revision %REV% %REPOS%"
 --output-document="-"
 --timeout=2
 http://localhost:8080/jenkins/subversion/%UUID%/notifyCommit?rev=%REV%
```

But this one doesn't work. It didn't trigger Jenkins to build any more. What did I do wrong in the second script?

I think the problem exists in running "svnlook" in the batch file. I run `svnlook uuid [REPO LOCATION]` in cmd, and it shows the id. Then I put it in a batch file:

```
SET UUID=svnlook uuid [REPO LOCATION]
ECHO %UUID%
```

Running the above batch file doesn't output the id. It shows just `svnlook uuid [REPO LOCATION]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally my `post-commit.bat` looks like:

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (
'svnlook uuid %REPOS%'
) DO (
SET UUID=%%a
)

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%b IN (
'svnlook changed --revision %REV% %REPOS%'
) DO (
SET POST=%%b
)

C:\wget_for_win\wget ^
    --header="Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" ^
    --post-data="%POST%" ^
    --output-document="-" ^
    --timeout=2 ^
    http://localhost:8080/jenkins/subversion/%UUID%/notifyCommit?rev=%REV%
```

The post-commit hook is working now.

- For those who want the Windows version of wget, use [WGET for Windows](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/).